# MYSQL Workbench Import button missing

Tags: mysql, csv, import, workbench

I'm trying to import a .csv file into a table using MySQL WB.  It was working fine up until I truncated a table, now I seem to have edit access via the workbench revoked.  I've recreated the table from a create statement I have on backup, but the Import button is still not the.  The problem seems to be there for this specific table only, all other ones are fine.  Has anyone come across this before?

Comment: I also cannot delete rows, right-clicking the table has this option greyed out

Answer (score 13):

Ah, answered it myself )  just needed to ad primary key column

Comment: But why can't I import data without defining primary key for table

Answer (score 7):

Sometimes it can hidden in low display resolution (height < 960), I've overcome this issue by setting high resolution (height > 768) once. I think it would be help someone.

Comment: Do I have to change my laptop's display height ?

Comment: You have to change display resolution

Answer (score 3):

make sure you have at-least one column as Primary. otherwise the file load option wont show. I believe thats because it wants to make sure the primary key has no null value when importing data in.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you're on Windows. Go to **Import Progress**, and then you will find the button **Start Import**, and then click on it and there you go.

[Import progress location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CxR2Y.png)

[Click the button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Po8j.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).